# Cloudinary Image Transformation on Direct URL Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I am trying to upload Images through direct Cloudinary API call that comes with transformations. Right now, I'm only able to upload images that do not have transformation like this:

```
...

    const fileList = files;
    const data = new FormData();
    const { signature, timestamp } = await getSignature(); // Get returned sign and timestamp
    data.append("file", fileList[0]);
    data.append("signature", signature); // Signature
    data.append("timestamp", timestamp); // Timestamp
    data.append("api_key", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_KEY);
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_NAME}/image/upload`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
        mode: "cors",
      }
    );
    const file = await res.json();

...
```

But this time, I'm trying to upload an image that contains a watermark through the URL. I tried doing something like:

```
const res = await fetch(
      `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_NAME}/image/upload/l_obra_watermark`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
        mode: "cors",
      }
    );
```

But it always arrives to a CORS error. Is it possible to apply transformation through URL? How else would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I didn't do the syntax properly. I learned this by reading the docs and applying it on my own code and I realized that I was supposed to put the transformations inside the signature like so:

```
const cloudinaryHandler = async (
  _req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) => {
  // Must be UNIX format
  const timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

  // Signature
  const signature = cloudinary.utils.api_sign_request(
    {
      timestamp: timestamp,
      eager: "w_400,h_400,g_south_east,x_5,y_5,l_obra_watermark,o_76",
    },
    process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET //API Secret (MUST BE HIDDEN IN ENV)
  );

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.json({ signature, timestamp });
};
```

and not in `data.append()`.

Here is the docs where I learned this from:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#manual_signature_generation

Answer (score 0):

You can include the required transformations in an upload preset and use this upload preset in your upload call like this:

data.append("upload_preset", my_preset);

You can read about the upload presets here:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_presets